# gnuplot splot approximation or interpolation?

Tags: gnuplot, interpolation, heatmap

I'm rendering heat map using gnuplot splot with pm3d using next script

```
set view map
set dgrid3d
set pm3d interpolate 20,20
set palette defined(\
0 '#00dc00',\
3640 '#00ff00',\
32767 '#c8ff00',\
61894 '#ff8000',\
65535 '#ff7000') 
splot "d:/source.dat" using 1:2:3 with pm3d
```

"source.dat" file contains next values

```
0 0 36
1 0 36
2 0 36
0 1 36
1 1 36
2 1 36
0 2 36
1 2 36.9
2 2 36
```

Gnuplot produced next image

[image]

But I'm not understand why I have red color in top center point which is equals to 36.6 temperature according to the pallete. In data file I have 36.9 instead of that. It seems to me that gnuplot approximated this value. How I could configure in to interpolate all points?

Comment: The point with value 36.9 is not on your interpolated grid.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean? (sorry, I'm completely new in gnuplot). How it could be possible that gnuplot skipped one of my points?

Comment: Okay, I get it. Instead of "set dgrid3d" I should use "set dgrid3d 3,3". After this change I get right heat map.